# How to get name from second table by referring to an ID from first table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am new to the SQL Server world. I have two tables for example

```
gameDetails(gid, name, categoryid, companyid, year)
```

and

```
gameSubDetails(id, name, delflag)
```

In `gameDetails` I've stored ids of `gameSubDetails` in `categoryid` and `companyid`.

Now if I want to search any value in `gameDetails` based on the criteria also from `gameDetails`, How can I get the name of the `Category` and `Company` from `gameSubDetails`?

For example I want to search all the values of `gameDetails` where `year = 2015`.

So I wrote query as

```
select 
    g.gName, gsub.name as catid, gsub.name as compid 
from 
    gameMaster g, gameSubDetails gsub 
where 
    g.compid = gsub.id 
    and g.year = '2015'
```

But it shows only company name in both (catid, compid), but even if I try to put another where condition with catid like `where g.compid = gsub.id and g.catid = gsub.id and .year='2015'` it does not return any records.

Please suggest what is the best way to work upon this scenario.

Note: `CategoryId` and `CompanyID` are stored in same table `gameSubDetails` just Id is different.

Comment: mysql or (MS)SQL-Server? Please remove tags for products that are not relevant here

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Why can't you query the `year` straight from `gameDetails`?

Comment: I think as you are selecting same columns and giving only alias different hence, it shows  same value in catid and compid.gsub.name as catid, gsub.name as compid

Comment: @Trushna yes Category id and Company id are both same from GameSubDetaills but the IDs will be different

Comment: @TheRenaissance I can do that easily but it will display IDs in catid and compid, instead of that i want to display names of them getting that from another table

Comment: @InfiRazor Can you explain what the different variables are storing more clearly? Like `gid` in `gameDetails` and `id` in `gameSubDetails`? I'm having trouble figuring out what matches to what.

Comment: Give all DDL & matching query. Also example input, output & desired output. Indeed please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use subselects like

```
select g.gName
 , (select name from gameSubDetails where id = g.compid) as company
 , (select name from gameSubDetails where id = g.catid) as category 
from gameMaster g
where g.year='2015'
```

or joins like

```
select g.gName,comp.name,cat.name
from gameMaster g 
left join gameSubDetails comp on g.compid = comp.id
left join gameSubDetails cat on g.catid = cat.id
where g.year='2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding, you're looking to do a join to get the name from `gameSubDetails` based on the year in `gameDetails`. Specifics will depend on which particular flavor of SQL, but here's one:

```
SELECT gsub.name
FROM gameSubDetails as gsub JOIN gameDetails as gd ON gsub.id = gd.gid
WHERE gd.year = '2015'
```

This is assuming the `gid` mentioned is the game `id` mentioned in `gameSubDetails`, though it sounds from your comments like it may be storing two different variables which match the companyid and categoryid. If that is the case, replace `gid` and `id` with any field from `gameDetails` which matches a field from `gameSubDetails` *completely*, not just part of it.